# create Array inside object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to create an array of object shown in below code.

```js
myobj = [{
  name: "abc",
  "code": "aa",
  "isdefault": 1
}, {
  name: "abc",
  "code": "bb",
  "isdefault": 0
}, {
  name: "bcd",
  "code": "ac",
  "isdefault": 0
}]
var codeids = {};
$.each(myobj, function(key, val) {
  console.log(val); //  ==>{name: "abc","code":4,"isdefault":1 }
  codeids[val.name] = {
    [val.code]: val.isdefault
  }; // I want  codeids['abc'] should be ==> [{"aa":1},{"ab":0}...]

});
console.log(codeids)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

final codeids should be ==>

```
{"abc":[{"aa":1},{"ab":0}],"bcd":[{"ac":0},{"cd":0}],...}*
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it also using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/Reduce) method.

```js
let myobj = [{
  name: "abc",
  "code": "aa",
  "isdefault": 1
}, {
  name: "abc",
  "code": "bb",
  "isdefault": 0
}, {
  name: "bcd",
  "code": "ac",
  "isdefault": 0
}]

let y = myobj.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (!acc[obj.name]) {
    acc[obj.name] = []
  }

  acc[obj.name].push({
    [obj.code]: obj.isdefault
  })

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to push onto an array, not just assign directly to the property.

```js
myobj = [{
  name: "abc",
  "code": "aa",
  "isdefault": 1
}, {
  name: "abc",
  "code": "bb",
  "isdefault": 0
}, {
  name: "bcd",
  "code": "ac",
  "isdefault": 0
}]
var codeids = {};
$.each(myobj, function(key, val) {
  if (!codeids[val.name]) {
    // initialize empty array
    codeids[val.name] = [];
  }
  codeids[val.name].push({
    [val.code]: val.isdefault
  });
});
console.log(codeids);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the values from the object and check if the property exists for the array.

This approach works without `jquery`.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: "abc", code: "aa", isdefault: 1 }, { name: "abc", code: "bb", isdefault: 0 }, { name: "bcd", code: "ac", isdefault:0 }],
    codeids = {};

array.forEach(({ name, code, isdefault }) => {
    if (!codeids[name]) codeids[name] = [];
    codeids[name].push({ [code]: isdefault });
});

console.log(codeids);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a plain JS forEach loop, no Jquery needed:

```js
myobj = [{
  name: "abc",
  "code": "aa",
  "isdefault": 1
}, {
  name: "abc",
  "code": "bb",
  "isdefault": 0
}, {
  name: "bcd",
  "code": "ac",
  "isdefault": 0
}]

var codeids = {};
myobj.forEach(({name, code, isdefault}) => {
  if (!codeids[name]) codeids[name] = [];
  codeids[name].push({[code]: isdefault});
})

console.log(codeids)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this should do it:

```js
myobj = [
    {name: "abc","code":"aa","isdefault":1 },
    {name: "abc","code":"bb","isdefault":0 },
    {name: "bcd","code":"ac","isdefault":0 }
  ];
  
var codeids = {};

myobj.forEach((val) => {
  if(!codeids.hasOwnProperty(val.name)) {
    codeids[val.name] = [];
  }
  const newItem = {};
  newItem[val.code] = val.isdefault;
  
  codeids[val.name].push(newItem);
});

console.log(codeids);
```